# Packages path in wheel

Tags: python-wheel

I am creating a wheel where I am not using any setup.py . This is my structure. src/folder(wheel name & has many folders)/ but my packages that I use from this artifact are in src/folder/x and locally I have set this X folder as source root so I don't have to do from import.X.method Instead I can directly do from method import whatever.

```
-repo-name

    -folder 1
    -folder 2
    -src
       -package-name
           -folder 1
           -build
           -configs
           -folder 2
           -libraries (X)
             - we have 10 different folders here for all the functions and libraries.
       -package.egg-info
```

Unfortunately when the wheel gets published it doesn't save this source root information and my code doesn't work.

my pyproject.toml has this code but when I change src to the X, wheel only save X folders and discards everything else.

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

Is there a solution where I can mark something as source root when publishing the wheel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be resolved by adding the path to source in pyproject.toml .

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src", "another src"]
```